# Need Javascript to open a web page in full screen after logging in

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one login.aspx page one master page(Master.master). When I click on login button, my web page should view in full screen mode.This should happens automatically when user credentials  are correct.Master page should open in full screen mode.

I don't want it in new window(pop up window). I don't want to ask user press F11.It should work

in all browsers.(mainly in firefox and Internet Explorer)

I tried with below codes. But it is not working fine. Please correct my code or suggest me new code.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function fullscreen() 
{ 
window.open('page.php','kyscorp','width='+screen.width+',height='+screen.height+',top=0,left=0'); 
} 
</script>
```

I wrote in Master.master aspx page.

Regards,

nj

Comment: what happens when you adding this? Can i see the page?

Comment: It is not possible to view a webpage in full screen mode (similar to F11) programmatically. You can maximize a pop-up page to fill the entire screen using code similar to what you have but it will require opening a pop-up (which is blocked on most *modern* browsers) and not the existing window. 

PS. We should be grateful that this is not possible. :)

Comment: I agree with eapen.  I doubt you can pull that off without using ActiveX, and forcing your users into using IE.

Answer (score 0):

use `window.Location` instead `window.open`

```
window.location="page.php";
```